# Wordpress - how to order the get_categories result

Tags: wordpress, categories

I read the documentation of the codex but i can't order the get_categories() result just like parent,childrens.

I tried:

```
echo $product->get_categories();
```

and the results is the print of children,parents.

I also Tried following the Codex:

```
get_categories(array('orderby' => 'parent'));
```

but it print the word "parent"

How can I?
Sorry for the stupid question

Comment: What have you tried? What exact problem are you having? Please edit your question to add the relevant code that you're having trouble with.

Comment: did it, hope now is more understandable

Answer (score 0):

Check out here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92267/adding-multiple-parents-in-get-categories.

Basically you need specify parent id and then you'll get children. If you need to order from many parents then you'll need to query each parent.